# SVG as image view in different location

Tags: android, svg, android-imageview

I have read some questions here about SVG in android and comparing each answer and i found out that answers are similar in each other. My question is, Is it possible to use SVG format in `imageView` but in different locations?Many answers are in common location

```
// Parse an SVG resource from the "raw" resource folder
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
```

What i want is not`getResources(), R.raw.android`. 
I wanted to locate in a specific folder like

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/JunieFolder/junie_screenShot" + now + ".png";
```

I wanted to change to change any images in`imageView` dynamically.
Is it possible to achieve this?

`

Below is the code to view svg format

```
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/JunieFolder/junie_screenShot" + now + ".svg";
File file = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
svgImageView.setImageURI(uri);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.android); 
    imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
   imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); 
   //setContentView(imageView);
   svgImageView.setImageURI(uri)
```

I think this is the way to select image from a folder

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromString(path);
```

not

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.android);
```

Comment: "Is it possible to use SVG format in imageView but in different locations?" -- that will depend on what library you use to show the SVG images. There are [several libraries to choose from](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/96).

Comment: i used this one svg-android v2011. but i cant get make it work. Path is in string but library uses int. I will make a try. Thanks for the Info Sir

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir, I'm just starting to learn, in your opinion what library will fit in my need?

Comment: I have not used any of them, so I am not in position to make a recommendation -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make this work using the [AndroidSVG](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) library. The `SVGImageView` class has a method `setImageURI`, so you could do something like this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/JunieFolder/junie_screenShot" + now + ".svg";
File file = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
svgImageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

You can also use the `setImageAsset` and `setImageResource` methods to load the SVGs from the assets or the resources.

Comment: sir i add the code can you take a look. whats wrong with it?